# Passport expiry and blue card validity

Tags: germany, blue-card, passport, work-permit

My non-EU passport expires in 18 months. If I apply for a German blue card, how much would the validity of the blue card be? Will it be for the full duration (say 4 years) or would it be for just 18 months (which is my passport's validity)?

When I renew my non-EU passport from Germany, are there any procedures to be followed with respect to the blue card?

During my non-EU passport renewal from Germany, I will not have my passport with me. But German law considers it a requirement to always have a passport for foreigners. If the German police randomly ask me to show my ID during this period of renewal, what would happen?

Lastly if the passport expires (because I fail to renew it on time), will my stay in Germany with an expired passport but valid blue card be considered illegal?

Comment: The validity of your residence permit is tied to your passport, and you will have to get a new residence permit when you get a new passport.

Answer (score 2):

> If I apply for a German blue card, how much would the validity of the blue card be?

Up to 4 years **or** in cases that you have a time restricted contract, the length of the contract plus 3 months. ([§18(4) - Principle of skilled immigration; general provisions - AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0400))

> When I renew my non-EU passport from Germany, are there any procedures to be followed with respect to the blue card?

No, but you should report that you have a new passport to the Immigration Office.

> During my non-EU passport renewal from Germany, I will not have my passport with me. But German law considers it a requirement to always have a passport for foreigners.

You must ***possess** a recognised and valid passport* ([§3 - Passport requirement - AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0072)), which is not the same as always having it with you at all times. In most cases a country will cancel the old passport after issuing a new passport. If this is not the case, you should ask your Consulate for a written confirmation that they have your passport while it is being renewed. Send a copy of this to the Immigration Office.

> If the German police randomly ask me to show my ID during this period of renewal, what would happen?

You would show your **residence permit** card, which **within** Germany, is a valid form of identification.

> Lastly if the passport expires (because I fail to renew it on time), will my stay in Germany with an expired passport but valid blue card be considered illegal?

You are required to undertake **reasonable** measures to insure that you have a valid passport. Keeping some form of proof when you made the, timely, renewal application is a good idea. Should the process take longer than estimated (i.e. beyond your control), then keep the Immigration Office informed of the situation.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, the validity of the blue card is NOT related to the validity of the passport, correct?

Comment: @patstewart If it was, then §18(4) would include such a statement as an extra 'and' condition. Also §5 meantions only that you must have a valid passport when a residence permit is *granted* (and no meation of restricting it due to the passport validaty).

Comment: This is not correct, the validity of your residence permit is tied to the validity of your passport, when you get a new passport, you must apply for a new residence permit, but this is a shorter procedure than the first time. Source: I lived in Germany for many years on a Blue Card. When you apply for your residence permit, the officer will tell you about its validity and how it relates to your passport.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Before the cards were issued (and the permit was a sticker in the passport), this was certainly true. But I found no reference to this in the present day laws.

Comment: Might not be in the law but in some other legal procedure or statute, it is too detailed to be in the law itself. I am giving my experience as recent as middle of 2021. And the residence permit has fields (Anmerkungen/Remarks) that refer to the passport by number and expiry date. And note I am talking about the credit-card size cards that are issued as residence permits.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, I assumed that. [Section 78 - Documents with an electronic storage and processing medium](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1629) discribes this.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy However §51(1)(1) also says that a residence Titel can be terminated if, after a resonable period of time **after** a passport has expired, a new one is not presented. This would not be needed if such a title is **never** issued longer than the passport. Multiple lawyer sites also state the 2 are independent of each other. The may be a *can* rule on who long it will be issued, but the AufenthG itself does not state that.

Comment: You are talking about theory, I am talking about practice. I have residence permits that expired together with my passport, and the officer in the Migrationsamt told me the permit can be issues only until my passport expiry.